# Android: Two actvities as launchers

Tags: android, android-activity, simultaneous

I'm developing locker application. I created service and receiver to hide default android locker. But for few days I have problem with settings activity. I'm looking for a solution, how to make two activites as launchers. I want to make something like that:
Locker activity is only launched when phone is locked. And Settings activity only when I press app icon in menu. Is it possible to programme?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think you can create two launchers but why not have a launcher activity and then, after checking the settings you need, use an intent to start the correct activity you need?

Comment: I wrote something like that: KeyguardManager kgMgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
  boolean showing = kgMgr.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
  if (!showing) {
   Intent i = new Intent(StartLockScreen.this, SettingsActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
  } else {
   Intent i = new Intent(StartLockScreen.this, LockActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
  }
  finish();, it's only working for LockActivity, Settings still doesn't show. But after pushing pp icon, lockscreen doesn't appear so half success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to launch the same activity but changing the content view (into onCreate) for each situation. Something like:

```
if (isLocked()) {
    setContentView(R.layout.locker_activity);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
}
```

Comment: I don't think he just want's to change the layout but actualy launch in different activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one activity as launcher and use Fragments to load what you want. Something like this:

```
public class LauncherActivity extends FragmentActivity {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Fragment fragment;
if (isLocked()) {
    fragment = new LockerFragment();
}   
else {
    fragment = new SettingsFragmentFragment();
}
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_id,fragment).commit();
```

}